# show image when table cell is click

Tags: jquery, css

I have a 4x4 table where I want to use jquery to display a random image on a cell that I click on. When the page load table is empty the image only load when a user clicks on the cell. I am testing this only on one cell at the moment to get it to work before implementing it on other cells. Currently when the page loads the cell is empty but when I click on the empty cell the image is doesn't load

```js
var random_images = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3"]

function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
  path = path || 'images/'; // default path here
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgAr.length);
  var img = imgAr[num];
  var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
  document.write(imgStr);
  document.close();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#img1").click(function() {
    $("#img1").show();
  });
});
```

```css
#img1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td id="img1">
      <script>
        getRandomImage(random_images);
      </script>
    </td>
    <td>
      <script>
        getRandomImage(random_images);
      </script>
    </td>
    <td>
      <script>
        getRandomImage(random_images);
      </script>
    </td>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do it the way you want, so if you want to load a random image, I suggest you do the following:

Add an image with a class to your `td`:

```
<td id="img1">
  <img class="loadImg" src="" />
</td>
<td>
  <img class="loadImg" src="" />
</td>
<td>
  <img class="loadImg" src="" />
</td>
```

Then we change your script a bit.

```
$(".loadImg").each(function() {
  $(this).attr("src",getRandomImage(random_images));
});
```

Also please note you haven't closed your `<tr>`

**Demo**

```js
var random_images = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3"]

function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
  path = path || 'images/'; // default path here
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgAr.length);
  var img = imgAr[num];
  var imgStr = path + img;
  return imgStr;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table .img p").click(function() {
    $(this).next().attr("src", getRandomImage(random_images)).show();
    $(this).hide()
  });
});
```

```css
table .img img {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="img">
      <p>loadImg 1</p>
      <img class="loadImg" src="" />
    </td>
    <td class="img">
      <p>loadImg 2</p>
      <img class="loadImg" src="" />
    </td>
    <td class="img">
      <p>loadImg 3</p>
      <img class="loadImg" src="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: still, when I click on the empty cell the image doesn't load

Comment: No, this code loads the scripts as it runs, try to inspect an image in the demo and you can see it has a path. Do you wish that it loads when you click?

Comment: yes, i hide all the images on page load and i want to show the image on a cell when the cell is click

Comment: @user11766958 try to run the demo now and also look at the changes I made to the HTML in the demo